# Uploaded file's tmp_name does not exist

Tags: php, upload, multipart

I've been wrangling my brain for the last day trying to fix this.

Basically, the temp file set in `$_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']` does not exist.

The file is apparently getting uploaded, as shown in the below `print_r()` of `$_FILES`:

```
Array
(
    [logo] => Array
        (
            [name] => Channelcat.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php26YfhY
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 152142
        )

)
```

The file permissions on my `/tmp` directory are apparently 777. I suspect that this problem may have to do with the shared hosting it's using though.

And below is basically what I'm trying to do with the file.

```
$logo = $_FILES['logo'];

if($logo['size'] > (1024000)) {
    die('File size is too large.');
}

$path = __DIR__ . '/uploads/'. $logo['name'];

move_uploaded_file($logo['tmp_name'], $path);
```

I've tried using `is_uploaded_file($logo['tmp_name'])`, which returns false and `realpath($logo['tmp_name'])` which returns an empty string.

`move_uploaded_file` doesn't error, but doesn't move the file to the specified directory either.

Comment: `php26YfhY` is a file name. Yes, files can have no extension.

Comment: `php26YfhY` is file name then what is `Channelcat.jpg`??

Comment: For all of you - a __manual__ http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @jayme_brereton $path = __DIR__ . '/tmp/'. $logo['name']; what is you path variable output

Comment: you have to check `php_value upload_max_filesize 6M` in php.ini file

Comment: If you are developing on Windows like me, you can see a dump file that showing errors at C:\Windows\Temp called as "php**VERSION**_errors.log". It helps.

Comment: and last but not least , your form tag must include enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @u_mulder I'll edit the question, but it doesn't change the fact that the file simply does not exist, I've tried using `is_uploaded_file` and that returns false, I've tried `real_path` and that returns an empty string.


@VasimVanzara that's intentional, I'm trying to move the uploaded file to a folder in the same directory as the script with the name "tmp", sorry for any confusion.

The max upload filesize is 64MB.


I'm not using a Windows server.


And yes, I'm using the multipart form type.

Answer (score 0):

When you have set some **open_basedir** variable in the php.ini file, the file upload works, the **$_FILE** array gets populated and even shows the **tmp_name** subkey, still files are not written to disk, which results in a puzzling situation, as no further errors are reported being the **error** subkey set to 0.

Solution is to set the temp folder to some subfolder inside the **open_basedir** php.ini variable.